# If a,b and c are sides of a triangle, then prove that the following polynomial has no real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, polynomials

This is the polynomial: $$a^2x^2+(b^2+a^2-c^2)x+b^2=0$$

Now this is my progress:

Assuming l,m, and n are sides of a triangle, then $$|m-n|\lt l\lt m+n$$
Also, if a second degree polynomial in the form $kx^2+px+q$ has real roots, then $$p^2-4kq\ge 0$$
 In this case, if there are no real roots, $$(b^2+a^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2\lt 0$$
 $$b^2+a^2-c^2\lt 2ab$$
 But by the first equation, $$a+b\gt c$$

$$a^2+b^2-c^2\gt 2ab$$ 
 Wich actually proves by contradiction there ARE real roots. What did I do wrong?

Comment: From $|a-b|<c<a+b$, we have $(a-b)^2<c^2<(a+b)^2$, hence $-2ab<c^2-a^2-b^2<2ab$, or $|a^2+b^2-c^2|<2ab$ and finally $(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2<4a^2b^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answers the `What did I do wrong?` part of the question

> In this case, if there are no real roots, $$(b^2+a^2-c^2)^2-4a^2b^2\lt 0$$
>    $$b^2+a^2-c^2\lt 2ab$$

The two inequalities are not equivalent, since $b^2+a^2-c^2$ can be either positive or negative (remember that it is $0$ for right triangles by Pythagora's). What the first inequality *is* equivalent with, instead, is:

$$\left|b^2+a^2-c^2\right|\lt 2ab \quad \iff \quad -2ab \lt b^2+a^2-c^2\lt 2ab \tag{1}$$

> But by the first equation, $$a+b\gt c$$ 
>    $$a^2+b^2-c^2\gt 2ab$$

The second inequality does not follow, in particular $2ab$ has the wrong sign. Instead, if you square the first inequality you get: $$a^2+b^2 - c^2 \gt -2ab \tag{2}$$

If you square $|a-b| \lt c$ though, *then* you get:

$$a^2+b^2 - c^2 \lt 2ab \tag{3}$$

Note that the last two inequalities $(2),(3)$ put together give $(1)$ and therefore complete the proof.

Answer (score 9):

Nice exercise. It is well known (and not difficult to prove) that a second-degree polynomial has no real roots iff its discriminant is negative. The discriminant of the given polynomial is
$$ (b^2+a^2-c^2)^2-4a^2 b^2 = (a^2+2ab+b^2-c^2)(a^2-2ab+b^2-c^2) $$
or
$$ (a+b+c)(a+b-c)\color{red}{(a-b-c)}(a-b+c) $$
that is clearly negative by the triangular inequality or, equivalently, by [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula).